# When I try adding a new site to iis 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 it says it already exists

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, iis-8.5

When I try adding a new site to iis 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 it says it already exists. This is the first site I'm trying to add. I am not finding where this site may or may not exist.

Essentially what I am trying to do is copy my websites to a new web server. The web servers are both in Azure on VM's. Endpoints are set and static IP is set. There is one site, that when I try to create it, it errors out and informs me that it already exists.

Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7

[Error Pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QSE9.png)

Comment: Screenshots would help.

Comment: Have you also go the default site?

Comment: There are no sites set up at all. I get the error when I try to add the first site. There were sites here previously and were deleted. Could there be a config file somewhere that sets the bindings, and how many files to look through to find the culprit?

Comment: The IIS default site is working and server is responding.

Comment: After removing IIS and re-adding to server roles, I was able to add new site. I am still having the issue of the server redirecting to the old one when using the new server's IP address. Very confusing, if not frustrating.

Comment: Was able to resolve this by temporarily changing the bindings.